# How to use anything.el to open files from a certain directory

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to configure anything.el that that it open files from a certain predefind directory. At the moment it just works for the current directory.

How would that work?

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should have a look at [AnythingSources#Directory of files](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnythingSources#toc38)? Is it what your looking for?